# Show price gross and net

Tags: shopware6

I would like to show the gross price and net price on the product pages. Can I do this without a purchased extension? And if so how?
Thanks in Advance

Yours sincerely, Andre

I would like to know if my problem can be solved and how it can be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're showing gross prices initially, you can simply calculate the net price by subtracting the tax.

```html
{% set price = page.product.calculatedPrice %}

{% if page.product.calculatedPrices|length == 1 %}
    {% set price = page.product.calculatedPrices.first %}
{% endif %}

{% set tax = price.calculatedTaxes.first.tax %}
{% set priceGross = price.unitPrice %}
{% set priceNet = priceGross - tax %}

Gross: {{ priceGross|currency }}<br>
Net: {{ priceNet|currency }}
```