# How to export the net price / Tax value on product-feeds

Tags: shopware6

I would like to export the net price on product-feed exports.
Unfortunately the documentation does not mention a tax value, nor a net price variable.
https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/Productcomparison#variables

I already tried the variables used here:
[Show price gross and net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75919015/show-price-gross-and-net)

But it seems they are not valid in the feedexport.

Is therey any other way to get the prices exportet without VAT?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Which config did you use exactly ? And which error message are you getting?

Comment: Hi Alex. I do not get any error. The output is just empty. I assume there is no way to export it. Or they missed to mention the variables in the docs.

Comment: I tried "product.price.netPrice" however this triggers the following Error during Export:

`400:  Failed rendering string template using Twig: Neither the property "netPrice" nor one of the methods "netPrice()", "getnetPrice()"/"isnetPrice()"/"hasnetPrice()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Pricing\\PriceCollection"`